# AngularJS ng-click function doesn't work for parent directive to child directive

Tags: angularjs

I have declared the following custom directives on my application,

```
angular.module("MyApplication")
  .directive("ParentTableRow", ParentTableRowDirective)
  .directive("item", itemDirective);

itemDirective.$inject = ["$compile"];
```

Here is the function for parentTableRow directive,

```
function ParentTableRowDirective($compile){
return {
  restrict: "A",
  replace:true,
  template: '<div ng-repeat="item in collection" item="item">' +
  '<div class="row {{item.type}}">' +
  '<div class="col-md-6 item-name" ng-click="showChilds(item)">{{item.name}}</div>' +
  '<div class="col-md-2 item-ask"><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="item.ask" ng-click="selectItems(item,\'ask\')" /></div>' +
  '<div class="col-md-2 item-proj"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.current_projection" ng-click="selectItems(item,\'current_projection\')" /></div>' +
  '<div class="col-md-2 item-reg"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.registration" ng-click="selectItems(item,\'registration\')" /></div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>',
  scope: {
    collection: '='
  }
};
}
```

And Here is the function for ItemDirective,

```
function itemDirective($compile){
return {
  restrict: "A",
  scope: {
    item: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

  },
  controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){

    $scope.selectItems = function(item,type) {
      angular.forEach(item.children, function(item){
        if(type == 'ask') {
          item.ask = !item.ask;
        }
        else if(type == 'current_projection') {
          item.current_projection = !item.current_projection;
        }
        else if(type == 'registration') {
          item.registration = !item.registration;
        }          

      });
    }

  }
}
}
```

Problem statement: Select/Unselect checkbox event($scope.selectItems) is getting triggered for all child elements(ItemDirective) except the parent element.

Comment: You're not using `$compile` anywhere.  Why do you have it?

Comment: Yes I am not using $compile now. So I can remove this itemDirective.$inject = ["$compile"];

Comment: is it possible that some code is missing ? I don't see where are you using your itemDirective in the html

Comment: Please find the html code below,
`<div parent-table-row="" collection="ctrl.tableData" selected-data="ctrl.selectedData"></div>`
initially we will assign json objects on tableData using some other directives. This Json objects will be displayed on the page based on above ParentTableRowDirective & itemDirective